# How do you unlock the full set of amiibo power armor?

Tags: splatoon-2

I have the amiibo, but I only have the head piece, when I scan it.

I used the squid, blue ink boy, and orange ink girl when I was lvl 10. I'm lvl 11 now, and I tried to claim my gear, but it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to win matches to unlock gear. Do not worry, I did this with Octoling Boy and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep leveling yourself up. You don't unlock something every time you level up. Besides if I was level 11, I'd be doing ranked battles.